# Blurred image view while using universal image loader in android

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am displaying user images in a list view. but all the images displayed in the listview is blurred. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10))
            .build();           

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .build();
        // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

[image]
[image]

First one is a displayed image in the image view and second one is a original image.

```
<ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/userPicView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/KEY_USER_PROFILE_UPPER"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
```

Comment: This happens when the width and height are more than that of the image.

Answer (score 0):

This happens as hannanessay said, when the width and height of the imageView are more than the image.

**Change:**

```
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

**To:**

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```